# webpack loader imports configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader

I'm trying to use webpack to require [wowjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wowjs), which is a browser plugin compiled from coffeescript.

the code in `dist/` expects to be executed in a global context. so in coffeescript it looks like:

```
class @WOW
  ...
```

which transpiles to

```
(function() {
  this.WOW = function() { ... }
}).call(this);
```

when executed in a global context this allows you to call the plugin elsewhere a la `new WOW().init()`.

I've been playing around with the [imports loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html), so I can make a require & call like so:

```
require("imports?this=>window!wowjs")
new window.WOW().init()
```

note that a call like `new WOW().init()` wouldn't work, because webpack wraps this code in it's own module / context. I can live with this, but it still feels like I'm missing something here?

In any case, if I try to move this to my `webpack.config.js` as suggested in the docs, I can't get it to work. My config looks like this:

```
{ 
  ...
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /wowjs/, loader: "imports?this=>window"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

The loader section seems pretty straight forward, but it just doesn't seem to work. The docs use an example like:

```
{ test: require.resolve('wowjs'), loader: 'imports?this=>window' }
```

but that didn't seem to work for me either.

I keep thinking that this must be a common problem amongst modules written in coffeescript, but I haven't been able to turn anything up.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get `require.resolve` to work as a Webpack test value. You can instead use a different regex to correctly match the NPM module.

```
{test: /wow.(min.)?js$/, loader: "imports?this=>window"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following configuration in a `webpack.config.js` should do the job:

```
"webpack": "^1.13.2"
"imports-loader": "^0.6.5"
```

```js
{
  // ...
  loaders: [{
     // this should work.
     test: /wowjs/, loader: "imports?this=>window",
     // this also should work (and believe is preferred in this case).
     //test: require.resolve('wowjs'), loader: "imports?this=>window"
  }],
  // ...
}
```

`test` property should point to the *target* file (or module) which should be wrapped (to get custom `this` value) or to which variables should be injected (e.g. `imports?$=jquery`).
In this case we're referring to *wowjs* module, which will be wrapped and get `this === window`.

It's worth to mention that `loaders` array should reside in `module` property of exported configuration. It's not clear whether this applies in the original case. But it was the reason that nothing worked when I tried to reproduce the behavior just copying the `loaders` object and pasting it to the configuration file.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: '...',
  module: {
    loaders: [{/*...*/}]
  },
  //...
};
```